# VS2010: Compile a C++ Project in 64 bit

Tags: c++, visual-studio, 64-bit

I want to compile a C++ DLL in 64 bin using Visual Studio 2010 Express. I know how to use the configuration manager in C#. Just select x64 as target platform and compile. But in C++,  there is only "Win32" available as target.

How can I compile a x64 bit DLL?

Comment: Create a new configuration in the configuration manager.

Comment: @rasmus VS 2010 Express does not have 64bit compilers.

Comment: I see. Sorry about that. Have only used professional myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual C++ Express does not include 64-bit tools by default. You can install Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) to get them.

For details, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s(v=vs.100).aspx